# ScrollView and subviews don't match between code and Storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, interface-builder

I have created a UIScrollView in my Storyboards file, and properly connected it to my controller IBOutlet attribute. Here is what it looks like in Storyboards:

- UIScrollView

  - UIView 1
  - UIView 2
  - UIView 3
  - Constraints
    ...

This is the code I am running on viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"COUNT: %d", [self.scrollView subviews].count);
    for(UIView *v in [self.scrollView subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"View: %@", v);
    }
}
```

I was, therefore, expecting to see my 3 views listed in my console log. However, it is printing something totally unrelated (2 UIImageViews?):

```
2014-09-17 13:06:33.155 Project[6333:652705] COUNT: 2
2014-09-17 13:06:33.156 Project[6333:652705] View: <UIImageView: 0x7b094460; frame = (233 124.5; 7 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0947c0>>
2014-09-17 13:06:33.156 Project[6333:652705] View: <UIImageView: 0x7b094fb0; frame = (236.5 121; 3.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b095080>>
```

I may be clearly doing something wrong here, but is there some sort of cache in Interface Builder or the Outlet connection itself?

Comment: are they UIView or UIImageViews? Are you sure they are set up correctly as IBOutlets in the Connection Inspector?

Comment: there are UIImageView and there are the scrollBars vertical and horizontal

Comment: @timpone they are definitely UIViews. I am not connecting them to my controller. I only connected my UIScrollView to my controller, and I expected the instance would come up with its subviews, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The image views are the scrollers at the edge of the scroll view. When `viewDidLoad` is called the view hierarchy hasn't been fully installed yet. Move your code into the `awakeFromNib` method instead (and watch out for the image views - generally don't rely on the `subviews`, keep explicit references to the views you want to access).

Comment: awakeFromNib doesnt bring my scroll view subviews (even though it is not bringing the UIImageViews either, now subviews count come as 0). And I really didnt want to connect every single view I want to access from my code. Maybe what I need is not possible after all, not sure.

Comment: can't tell from question, but IBOutlets should all be configured by viewDidLoad - correct?

Comment: look at outlet collections if you just want to enumerate the subviews. Do you see the subviews on screen?

Comment: @timpone, no, only at `awakeFromNib`